# XAMPP - ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: php, apache, rest, xampp, slim

For a schoolproject i need to create a REST-API (i choosed the Slim Framework for PHP)

I followed this Tutorial --> https://youtu.be/TcFUNG7M3VE

In this Tutorial he wants to create a Virtual host in XAMPP

At first I downloaded the slim Framework with Composer, after that I copied the Example from https://www.slimframework.com/

Now i wanted to access the Website via a Virtual Host:

1. I created a .htaccess File

`RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]`

2. then I modified the httpd-vhost.conf File in xampp\apache\conf\extra

I added those Code Snippets:

`NameVirtualHost *:81`

`<VirtualHost *:81>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/"
    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>`

`<VirtualHost *:81>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/myslimsite/public"
    ServerName myslimsite
</VirtualHost>`

3. And I wrote this in the "hosts" file in "C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc"

   `127.0.0.1       localhost
   127.0.0.1       myslimsite
   255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
   ::1             localhost`

When i want to access myslimlite instead of localhost i get this ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED Error

This is in the Error Log:
`AH00548: NameVirtualHost has no effect and will be removed in the next release C:/xampp/apache/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf:22
[Thu Oct 05 16:41:13.623467 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 8424:tid 236] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name`

Line 22 of httpd-vhost.conf is `NameVirtualHost *:81`

So i guess there is something wrong with the httpd-ssl.conf or the httpd-vhost.conf File?

Or have I done anything else wrong?

Just for your information, this is my first post in a forum like this, please tell me if i did anything wrong so that i can do it better next time.

Comment: use `<virtualHost *:80>` instead or you need to make apache listen to port 81 too

Comment: and dont forget to restart apache after you make config changes

Comment: apache is already listening at port 81 because its the first thing i change when i install xampp